# Remote Log out in SAML 2 is not redirecting to logout page

Tags: spring, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

Currently my JSF application is integrated with SAML Authentication process. Its works properly in case of log in and log out. It logs out to default page when I log out of my application. However when I log in  to my application and then go to another application connected with same SSO, and log out of that remote application, I am expecting my application to log out and redirect to default page, which is in my case index.xhtml. It is not doing it rather it is staying still and manual refreshing take me to error page, and log shows the error message:

```
2017-09-25 16:27:31,887 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutFilter - Logging out user 'null' and transferring to logout destination
```

Here is my part of Spring security XML doc:

```
    <bean id="samlFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
            <sec:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
                <sec:filter-chain
                        pattern="/saml/logout/**"
                        filters="samlLogoutFilter"/>
                <sec:filter-chain
                        pattern="/saml/SSO/**"
                        filters="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter"/>
                <sec:filter-chain
                        pattern="/saml/SingleLogout/**"
                        filters="samlLogoutProcessingFilter"/>
            </sec:filter-chain-map>
        </bean>
   <bean id="successLogoutHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler">
        <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/index.xhtml"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="logoutHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler">
        <property name="invalidateHttpSession" value="true"/>
        <property name="clearAuthentication" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Override default logout processing filters with the one processing SAML
        messages -->
    <bean id="samlLogoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutFilter">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="successLogoutHandler"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="logoutHandler"/>
        <constructor-arg index="2" ref="logoutHandler"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Filter processing incoming logout messages -->
    <!-- First argument determines URL user will be redirected to after successful
        global logout -->
    <bean id="samlLogoutProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter">
        <constructor-arg ref="successLogoutHandler"/>
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <ref bean="logoutHandler"/>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

According to SAML reference doc handler in samlLogoutProcessingFilter default redirect to logout.jsp, however I do not have logout.jsp. Besides, successLogoutHandler bean in my Spring security bean already redirects to index.xhtml.

is samlLogoutProcessingFilter override successLogoutHandler's default path and redirects to logout.jsp. If so, how do I set the redirect path here? Do I have to override filter to do this.

Here is the log after remote log out if it helps

```
2017-09-25 16:17:48,034 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.springframework.security.saml.storage.HttpSessionStorage - Storing message a3b826i8h616186339b11di025ade3c to session J1LGZJkLMbL8C0phmmrVRQXKQQPxdTdGHRZc8cQwdH8C0yDgKy4m!-1886365667!1506370667067
2017-09-25 16:17:48,034 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.springframework.security.saml.storage.HttpSessionStorage - Storing message a3b826i8h616186339b11di025ade3c to session J1LGZJkLMbL8C0phmmrVRQXKQQPxdTdGHRZc8cQwdH8C0yDgKy4m!-1886365667!1506370667067
2017-09-25 16:17:48,034 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.springframework.security.saml.storage.HttpSessionStorage - Storing message a3b826i8h616186339b11di025ade3c to session J1LGZJkLMbL8C0phmmrVRQXKQQPxdTdGHRZc8cQwdH8C0yDgKy4m!-1886365667!1506370667067
2017-09-25 16:17:48,034 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] INFO  org.springframework.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger - AuthNRequest;SUCCESS;fe80:0:0:0:81d7:2959:a2ab:891e%12;t2ua40620y5.com.dept-myApp;https://login-dev.dtd.org/osp/a/t1/auth/saml2/metadata;;;
2017-09-25 16:17:48,034 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] INFO  org.springframework.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger - AuthNRequest;SUCCESS;fe80:0:0:0:81d7:2959:a2ab:891e%12;t2ua40620y5.com.dept-myApp;https://login-dev.dtd.org/osp/a/t1/auth/saml2/metadata;;;
```

It seems that app is getting correct response, I think it is not redirecting to proper location.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: so I put the following in ready() method
         jsf.ajax.addOnError(function (data) {       
            alert(data.source.id + " " + data.type + " " + data.source.value + " "  + data.status + " " +  data.errorMessage + " " + data.responseXML);

IT prints out

Comment: so I put jsf.ajax.addOnError() in ready() method and got the following value:

       data.source.id =form:j_idt36
       data.type = error 
       data.source.value = undefined
       data.status = emptyResponse
       data.errorMessage = undefined
       data.responseXML = null

so, there is some sort of ajax error happening, I can catch this and redirect to landing page. It solves it temporarily but when log back in I get a page with xml structure, not rendered properly, until I refresh the page.